# "The files are identical" don't pop up at all even the files are identical in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, compare, devart, codecompare

When I click on a file in Visual Studio I don't get dialog that informs me that "The following files are identical:". It opens immediately compare tool.

Some time ago, I clicked on "Always Open" button on that dialog, and from then onwards VS always opens a compare tool. I use Devarts Code Compare.

**How to get back dialog that says that two files are identical?**

Comment: In Devarts Code Compare tool open Tools > Options > Environment > General. Check "Use binary quick comparison before opening" and the dialog is back next time you compare identical files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Devarts Code Compare tool open **Tools > Options > Environment > General**. Check **"Use binary quick comparison before opening"** and the dialog is back next time you compare identical files.

Comment: This worked for me to get the pop-up to show in Code Compare when it was previously missing on identical files.